# Exibir imagem ao lado do titulo do post relacionada de categoria

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme, plugin-wordpress

Preciso exibir uma imagem relacionada a categoria do *post* ao lado do titulo do *post*, então instalei o plugin [Taxonomy Images](https://wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomy-images/).

Estou tentando fazer a exibição através do comando utilizado pela documentação:

```
print apply_filters( 'taxonomy-images-queried-term-image', '' );
```

Mas infelizmente não funciona. Alguém já fez algo do tipo e pode me recomendar algum outro plugin ou me ajudar na execução desse?

Answer (score 1):

tenta isso:

```
print apply_filters( 'taxonomy-images-list-the-terms', '', array(
    'before'       => '',
    'after'        => '',
    'before_image' => '',
    'after_image'  => '',
    'image_size'   => 'detail',
    'post_id'      => get_the_ID()
) );
```

Comment: Funcionou! Obrigado! acrescentei apenas mais algumas coisas que especificas para o projeto. Obrigado!